# Why is this sequence of events increasing?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Asymmetric random walk $S_n$ with $p=P(X_i=1)=1-P(X_i=-1) \in (\frac{1}{2},1)$ and, given a < 0 < b, define the stopping time $T_{a,b}=\inf\{n\geq 0: S_n = a \text { or } b\}$. I don't see why the event $\{S_{T_{-1,n}}=-1\}$ with $n \geq b$ would be included in every event $\{S_{T_{-1,n+k}}=-1\}$ for any $k\geq 1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $\omega \in \{S_{T_{-1,n}} = -1 \}$, then $S_{T_{-1,n}(\omega)}(\omega) = -1$, that is for each $t < T_{-1,n}(\omega)$ we have $-1 < S_t(\omega) < n$. For $k \ge 1$ now $-1 < S_t(\omega) < n+k$, all $t < T_{-1,n}(\omega)$. Therefore, as $S_{T_{-1,n}(\omega)}(\omega) = -1$, we have $T_{-1,n+k}(\omega) = T_{-1,n}(\omega)$. This gives $S_{T_{-1,n+k}(\omega)}(\omega) = -1$ or $\omega \in \{S_{T_{-1,n+k}} = -1 \}$.

By the same argument, you can show that the sequence of events is increasing, that is
$$ 
\{S_{T_{-1,n}} = -1 \} \subseteq \{S_{T_{-1,n+1}} = -1 \} \subseteq \{S_{T_{-1,n+2}} = -1 \} \subseteq \cdots 
$$